# Are OpenMP environment variables readed at compile-time or run-time?

Tags: openmp

With OpenMP 4 you can use a set of environment variables, like `OMP_PROC_BIND` or `OMP_PLACES`.

Are these variables used during compile-time or run-time? Let's say I have to do some experiments changing these values, do I have to recompile the program each time to apply them? Or just re-run it?

Note: it is difficult to me to test this, because at the moment I don't have the possibility to recompile my test program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment variables affect the execution at **run-time**. You don't need to recompile the program. However, you should not modify the variables after the application was started.